# Display message on button_click

Tags: c#, vb.net, button, browser, webbrowser-control

I have a webBrowser control named `WebBrowser1` inside my form.
I pulled values to the check boxes and other controls using the following code:

```
 WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("LastName").SetAttribute("value", "MyLastname")'<--- pull value to the textbox
 WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("TermsOfService").SetAttribute("value", "yes")'<--- change the value of a check box
```

I need to display a message box when user clicks the button which is in the browser. 
How can i trace the click ?, even C# code are acceptable so i tagged to C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a handler to the button you want to monitor, as an example, i've added one after the DocumentCompleted event of the webbrowser control fires

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

    Dim htmlBtn As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("BtnID")

    If htmlBtn IsNot Nothing Then 
        AddHandler htmlBtn.click, AddressOf YourSub
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub YourSub()
    messagebox.show("clicked!")
End Sub
```